# An interview question on the performExecute() in a controller command or taskcommand

Tags: wcs

In a recent interview which i attended i was asked a question. It is as follows:

In a controller command we have a method named performExecute().But whenever we want to execute the controller command from any other controller command we will just call

```
controllerCmdObj.execute();
```

Why it is so?

Can anybody please answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Hey its the inheritence, you implement `controllercommand` interface or extend `controllercommandImpl`.

Inside the execute method of implemented super class they call `performExecute`.

So when you call your controller command's execute method the call goes to the execute of super class and from withing that the base class's `performExecute` gets called.